# My select statement here throws the Invalid column name error and I dont know how to solve it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time

This is my store procedure:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE SumOnDateReport
             @QueryDate DATETIME
        AS
            DECLARE @total_sec INT

            SELECT 
                @total_sec =  SUM((DATEPART(hh, TimeSpanColumn) * 3600) +
                                  (DATEPART(mi, TimeSpanColumn) * 60) +
                                   DATEPART(ss, TimeSpanColumn))
            FROM   
                InfoTable

            SELECT 
                @total_sec / (24 * 3600) AS total_days, 
                CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(s, @total_sec, 0)) AS total_datetime
            WHERE
                TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate

            RETURN
```

I have a table that consists of 2 columns, `TimeSpanColumn` and `TimeStampColumn`.

It yells at me for the last line:

```
WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate
```

it says

> Invalid column name

which my column name is exactly the one in my table.

Comment: You don't need to tell us to look at your code. We know this is the reason why you are posting in the first place :-)

Comment: there is no "from" clause in your main query, but there is "where" clause?

Comment: Your second `SELECT` doesn't have a  `FROM` clause .......

Comment: wow thank you for your answer. I love this website and its support and its editors :D ( now my question is actually a question :) ).  Tim Biegeleisen your right my bad :). marc_s I got it thank you buddy you helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second SELECT doesn't have a FROM clause ....... – marc_s